# Does Lorentz force affect the magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism

When a charged particle moves thru magnetic field, it is affected by Lorentz force. But does the magnetic field surrounding the particle experience a force opposite to the  particles Lorentz force ? For example, if the magnetic field is generated with permanent magnets, do the magnets experience opposite force than the moving particle ? Or is there no opposite force anywhere in the system to particles Lorentz force ?

Comment: See the answer here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114466/apparent-violation-of-newtons-3rd-law-and-the-conservation-of-angular-momentum

Comment: There seem to be two different questions here: the force on the electromagnetic fields (i.e. rate of momentum transfer to the field) is not the same as the force between a moving charge and a magnetic dipole.

Comment: The concept of a "force on a field" is a very subtle one. I am not sure it can be formulated consitently.

Comment: @SebastianRiese I try to exposure some aspects in the question from the link given by Bill N