# force of charged particles on a magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

Since charged particles are deflected in a magnetic field depending on the orientation of the magnetic and electric field, - according to Newton's third law - can a stream of charged particles push against a magnetic field with enough strength to push the magnet?

Comment: Duplicate http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/229573/applying-newtons-3rd-law-in-electromagnetic-systems/229620

Answer (score 0):

why not, It can happen and you can examine this by putting a charged rod close enough to a magnetic pendulum and observe its movements.

Comment: It might be that the charged rod will induce charges on the magnet and you will see the effect of the Coulomb force between the magnet and the charged rod?

Answer (score 0):

It is not just charged particles that get deflected. The charge must also be moving to get deflected by Lorentz force. This [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TKSfAkWWN0) will give you an idea to visualize how magnets work. Since magnetic force is an electrical force in the reference of moving particles and the laws of physics are same in all inertial frames, the magnet must get pushed back by Newton's law.

In simple terms, yes by Newton's law, the magnet must get pushed.