# In motional emf why doesn't the magnetic field due to the current in the moving rod exert force on the rod?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

When a metal rod moves in a magnetic field an emf is produced across its ends called motional emf. When a resistor is connected across it a current flows through it.Due to this current a magnetic field is produced. Doesn't this magnetic field produce a force on the rod?

Comment: [Related?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/229573/applying-newtons-3rd-law-in-electromagnetic-systems/232025)

Comment: Well, it **does** exert a force. Where did you read that it **doesn't**??

Comment: I was trying to upload a picture of the text but couldn't. Just wait I will try it again....

Comment: Consider a conducting loop being pulled out of uniform magnetic field.We are asked to find the magnetic force on the loop. My book has solved it taking the magnetic force that already existed.If we assume the magnetic field due to the loop exerted force on it then this should increase its velocity but this doesn't happen.

Comment: According to Lenz's law(an addition to the above comment)