# Force on current carrying wire due to moving charges

Tags: magnetic-fields, electrons

Consider a situation where an electron traveling at a very high velocity enters in a magnetic region created by a current carrying wire.
This means a force will act on the electron and it will deflect from its path.
So my question is will there be an opposite force on current carrying wire?

Comment: Obviously, due to newton's third law. No issues with that!

Comment: Interestingly, Newton's third.law does not apply. See Feynman's Lectures II, 26,27.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114466/253727