# How to explain radiation pressure without modern physics?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation

I was recently taught that radiation pressure $P$ is given by $\frac{I}{c}$ in a vacuum.

To derive this I wrote that from the fact that $I=\frac{Fv}{A}=> P=\frac{I}{c}$

However, according to classical physics, light is massless so how do I explain this using classical theory?

Here $I$ is intensity, $c=v$ = the speed of light, and A is the area of an arbitrary surface normal to the source.

Comment: That question was about a mechanical wave, I'm talking about EM waves

Comment: You do not need a photon picture to deduce that classical electromagnetic fields must carry both energy and momentum. For an example, see [Apparent Violation of Newton's $3^{\text{rd}}$ Law and the Conservation of Momentum (and Angular Momentum) For a Pair of Charged Particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114466/apparent-violation-of-newtons-3-textrd-law-and-the-conservation-of-momen/).

Comment: Thanks! @EmilioPisanty