# Conservation of Momentum violation with Lorentz Force

Tags: electromagnetism, momentum, plasma-physics, magnetostatics, magnetohydrodynamics

Note: I am describing this question using cylindrical coordinates $\hat{r}$, $\hat{\theta}$, $\hat{z}$.

I've been looking into how you could slow down a plasma moving downstream in a pipe using magnetic fields. Subsequently, this idea that using a radial magnetic field to impart an azimuthal force on the plasma, will make it slow in the $z$-direction, kept popping up.

My next question was, how an azimuthal force could possibly cause an acceleration in the $z$-direction. The answer I found was that, since the azimuthal force causes the particles in the plasma to start moving in $\hat{\theta}$, conservation of momentum (C.O.M.) would cause the $\hat{z}$ velocity to decrease. However, conservation of momentum doesn't apply when there are external forces on the system.

After reading further, I found that the logic that would cause conservation of momentum to apply is that, since the Lorentz force is acting on the particles within the plasma, when looking at the plasma holistically, the Lorentz force can be treated as an internal force, and the $\hat{z}$ momentum of the *whole* plasma would decrease.

Is any of this true? Would it be more accurate to say that the particles within the plasma are exerting a force back on the object, that generates the magnetic field, and that's how C.O.M. is achieved? Please help!

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114466/apparent-violation-of-newtons-3-textrd-law-and-the-conservation-of-momen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an external force acting and it *changes* the momentum of the charged particles in the plasma.

However, since the Lorentz force is ${\bf F} = q{\bf v}\times {\bf B}$ then the rate of doing work on the particles is ${\bf F}\cdot {\bf v} = 0$.

Thus although the momentum is changed and the charges are accelerated, no work is done and the kinetic energy of the particles is conserved. This means the *speed* of the particles remains constant; and if the velocity now has an azimuthal component, then the velocity in the z direction must decrease. The reason for the acceleration along the z axis is that once the particles have a $v_\theta$, then there is a force along the z axis of magnitude $qv_\theta B_r$.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and concise answer! Makes complete sense now.