# Doubt in Newton's 3rd law?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

[image]

In this question the answer was given options B and C. I have doubt in option B, according to me it should option A since according to newtons third law of motion forces should be equal and opposite in direction however small the element may be but when I try finding the direction of force using magnetic field the force should be perpendicular to the direction of the element and since it is not necessary for elements to be parallel hence F<sub>12</sub> + F<sub>12</sub> ≠ 0. Why is newtons 3rd law not valid for individual elements?

Comment: It's not the infinitesimal nature of the elements that's to blame for the apparent Newton 3 failure: the same problem arises for two long non-parallel current-carrying wires. But, of course, neither wire is a complete circuit.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114466/apparent-violation-of-newtons-3-textrd-law-and-the-conservation-of-momen

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Let me show you some details about this question.

As the left part of the above picture shows: the magnetic field that 2 gives 1 can be written as:
$$
B_{12}=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{I_1d\vec l_1\times\vec {r_{12}}}{r_{12}^3}
$$

And the force which $I_2$ feels is
$$
d\vec F_{12}=I_2d\vec l_2\times B_{12}=\frac{\mu_0I_1I_2}{4\pi}\frac{d\vec l_2\times(d\vec l_1\times\vec {r_{12}})}{r_{12}^3}
$$

Same for $I_1$
$$
d\vec F_{21}=I_2d\vec l_2\times B_{12}=\frac{\mu_0I_1I_2}{4\pi}\frac{d\vec l_1\times(d\vec l_2\times\vec {r_{12}})}{r_{12}^3}
$$

The direction of $dF_{12}$ and $dF_{21}$ is
$$
(d\vec{l_2}\cdot\vec r_{12})d\vec {l_1}-(d\vec l_1\cdot d\vec l_2)\vec r_{12}
$$

and

$$
(d\vec{l_1}\cdot\vec r_{21})d\vec {l_2}-(d\vec l_2\cdot d\vec l_1)\vec r_{21}
$$

Apparently not in same line, which means doubt in Newton's Law. But just like @Philip Wood said, in real world, always complete circuit like the right part of the picture. So we consider the whole loop.

Take $F_{12}$ as the example
$$
F_{12}=\iint dF_{12}=\frac{\mu_0I_1I_2}{4\pi}\oint_{L_1}\oint_{L_2}\frac{(d\vec{l_2}\cdot\vec r_{12})d\vec {l_1}}{r_{12}^3}-\frac{(d\vec l_1\cdot d\vec l_2)\vec r_{12}}{r_{12}^3}
$$

The first term can be written as
$$
\oint_{L_2}\frac{d\vec{l_2}\cdot\vec r_{12}}{r_{12}^3}=\oint\frac{d\vec r \cdot\vec r}{r^3}=\oint\frac{d\vec r}{r^2}=0\ (\text{because of the loop integrate})
$$

So only the second term will be remained. For the second terms, it's clear that $\vec F_{12}$ and $\vec F_{21}$ obey Newton's 3rd Law.

Hope my answer can help u!

Comment: Means in the hypothetical case in which only the small elements exists Newton's law will not hold?

Comment: @GarvChaudha The hypothetical case where the small element of current comes out of nowhere and disappears into nowhere violates a lot of conservation laws, not just Newton's third law. One has to take account of current conservation, and thus consider a closed circuit.