# How does one prove $\int_V\text{d}V\ \vec A=0$, given that $\vec A\cdot \vec{\textbf{n}}=0$ and $\nabla\cdot\vec A=0$, without using tensor analysis?

Tags: electromagnetism, tensor-calculus, integration, vector-fields

In the course of learning electrodynamics, I was asked to solve the problem following:

- $\vec A$ is a vector which satisfies $\vec A\cdot \vec{\textbf{n}}=0$, where $\vec{\textbf{n}}$
  is the normal vector of the surface of the volume $V$. Besides,
  $\nabla\cdot\vec A=0$ within the volume $V$. Please prove 
  $$\int_V\text{d}V\ \vec A=0.$$
- A standard solution is 
  $$\int_V\text{d}V \vec A=\int_V\text{d}V\,\nabla\cdot(\vec A\vec r )=\oint_S\text{d}\vec\sigma\cdot(\vec A\vec r
     )=\oint_S\text{d}\sigma\,\vec{\textbf{n}}\cdot(\vec A\vec
     r)=\oint_S\text{d}\sigma\ (0\times\vec r)=0.$$

However, does this solution mean that a person that has never learned tensor analysis can never solve the problem? I wonder whether there are any other solutions without using tensors.

Thank you for your reading the question. Waiting for your excellent answers.

Comment: @Frank Can you please explain the second step of your standard solution? Looks like you have integrated without having a differential dV, using the divergence theorem, that is.

Comment: @Frank Also since A and $\hat n$ are both normal to the boundary, they should be parallel to each other. Hence $A \times \hat n=0$.

Comment: You need to clarify the problem much more.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat I've made a mistake. I wanted to say that $\vec A\cdot\vec n=0$ originally. So sorry about that.

Comment: @Frank I still don't get the second and third steps of your standard solution.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Actually I have missed $\text{d}V$ in the second step. Besides, The second step could be explained as follows: $\nabla (\vec A \vec x)=\partial_i A_i x_j\hat{e_j}=x_j \hat{e_j}\partial_i A_i+A_i \hat{e_j}\partial_i x_j=x_j \hat{e_j}\partial_i A_i+A_i \hat{e_j}\delta_{ij}=\vec x\nabla\cdot\vec A+\vec A$, considering $\nabla\cdot \vec A=0$, then $\nabla (\vec A \vec x)=\vec A$. Finally, by Gauss's (or Green's) theorem of tensor fields, you could get the third step. Btw I used $\vec A\vec x$ as a dyad.

Comment: @Frank Please notice that in the second step of your standard solution you are taking the divergence of a scalar quantity. Is it at all possible?

Comment: Sorry about another mistake: In my last reply, the first term should be $\nabla\cdot (\vec A \vec x)$. Now the reply to your doubts: $\vec A \cdot \vec x$ is totally  different from $\vec A\vec x $, the later is called "dyad" as a kind of second order tensor.

Comment: I don't understand the question. $\int_V\text{d}V\ \vec A=0$ is a tensor analysis statement. How would a proof not use those methods?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty You could take $\int_V\text{d}V\vec A$ just as a vector statement. Supposing a man only familiar with vector analysis, I'm wondering wether he could prove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Tensor" analysis is just fancy language, and you can do this just fine without it. The essence of tensor analysis (or at least one way of looking at said essence; see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83743/motivation-for-tensor-product-in-physics/83759#83759) for more on that) is to do things component by component. Since
$$
\int_V\text{d}V\ \mathbf A=\sum_j \hat{\mathbf e}_j\int_V\text{d}V\ (\hat{\mathbf e}_j\cdot\mathbf A),
$$
it is sufficient to just consider the integral of the scalar quantity $A_j=\hat{\mathbf e}_j\cdot\mathbf A$. In this language, the proof is a reformulation of what you've given: because
$$
\nabla \cdot(x_j\mathbf A) = (\nabla x_j)\cdot\mathbf A + x_j \nabla\cdot\mathbf A = \hat{\mathbf e}_j\cdot\mathbf A,
$$
we can write 
\begin{align}
\int_V\text{d}V\ (\hat{\mathbf e}_j\cdot\mathbf A)
& =
\int_V\text{d}V\ \nabla \cdot(x_j\mathbf A)
\\ & =
\oint_S\text{d}\mathbf S\cdot(x_j\mathbf A),
\end{align}
which vanishes because $\mathbf A$ and $\mathrm d\mathbf S$ are orthogonal, and you're done. See? Easy! The tensor-analysis layer is just some fancy language on top to make everything come together slightly more coherently, but it is fundamentally the same proof.