# Multipole expansion of the magnetic energy of a distribution of current density

Tags: magnetic-moment, multipole-expansion

My professor left me as an exercise the multipole expansion of the energy of a distribution of current density in a magnetic field but I don't manage even to understand how to start.

The energy of the distribution is:
$$
U = - \int \vec{j} \cdot \vec{A} d^3 x 
$$

so I start expanding the potential:
$$
\vec{A} = \vec{A}(0) + [\vec{x}\cdot\nabla] \vec{A} +\frac{1}{6} \sum_{i,j}  (x_i x_j - |x|^2\delta_{i,j})\frac{\partial^2\vec{A}}{\partial_{x_i} \partial_{x_j}}
$$

And the energy can be decomposed into:
$$
U = - \int \vec{j} d^3 x \cdot \vec{A_0} -\int[\vec{j}\cdot \vec{x}\cdot\nabla]A (0) + \dots
$$

The task is to obtain the magnetic analogue of the energy of a distribution of charge:
$$
U=qV(0) - \vec{p}\cdot\vec{E}(0) +\frac{1}{6}Q:\nabla\vec{E}(0)
$$

The field produced by the distribution is negligible, only the energy of interaction between the distribution and the external field has to be taken into account.

I don't know how to handle even the second term of the expansion: how can I recover the vector $\vec{B}$ if there isn't any rotor in that expression? I searched for any vectorial identities but I found nothing useful. I feel this excercise is beyond my current abilities.

Comment: Do you just want the first few terms, or do you need the full series of multipoles? Is there some specific expression you want to arrive at?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I have edited the question  in order to clarify the task

Comment: That is unlikely to be possible as phrased, since you're missing at the very least a magnetic dipole interaction. You should quote the task exactly as it was given to you, along with your definitions for all relevant symbols (including in particular the normalization for the quadrupole tensors, and so on).

Comment: In the lecture we started from the expression: $$U=\int \rho V d^3 x$$ and by multipole expansion of the potential as: $$\vec{V} = \vec{V}(0) + [\vec{x}\cdot\nabla] \vec{V} +\frac{1}{6} \sum_{i,j}  (x_i x_j - |x|^2\delta_{i,j})\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial_{x_i} \partial_{x_j}}$$ and substituting the definition of total charge, dipole vector and quadrupole tensor Q we obtained that equation.
At the end of the lesson he simply said "try to do the same thing for the magnetic energy starting from $$U=-\int  \vec{J}\cdot\vec{A}d^3x$$ "

We used the : symbol for the double scalar product.

Comment: That information should go in the question, not as a comment, but frankly your comment only makes it worse. What makes you think that you will obtain an identical expression, instead of something analogous? You started with a static current distribution, so all the electric multipoles will be zero; instead, you should be looking for magnetic dipole and magnetic quadrupole interactions.

Comment: Yes the question is about the magnetic energy. I want to prove that $$ U = -\vec{\mu} \cdot \vec{B}  $$ and possibly the quadrupole term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things get pretty confusing if you attempt to do things in full vectorial notation, so I'll stick exclusively to component notation, with Einstein summations understood

You want to start with the expression
$$
\newcommand{\ue}{\hat{\mathbf e}}\newcommand{\z}{\mathbf 0}
\mathbf A(\mathbf r)=\ue_jA_j(\z)+\ue_jx_k\frac{\partial A_j}{\partial x_k}(\z)+\ue_j x_kx_l\frac{\partial^2 A_j}{\partial x_k\partial x_l}(\z)+ \cdots,
$$
and introduce it into your integral
$$
U=\int \mathbf j(\mathbf r)\cdot\mathbf A(\mathbf r)\mathrm d\mathbf r
$$
to get a multipole series. I will do the monopole and dipole terms and, since you're playing the fuzzy-definition game with the quadrupoles, leave those to you.

---

The monopole term is easy, and it comes from the zeroth-order term in the integral, which reads
$$
U_0=\int \mathbf j(\mathbf r)\cdot\mathbf A(\z)\mathrm d\mathbf r=\mathbf A(\z)\cdot\int \mathbf j(\mathbf r)\mathrm d\mathbf r,
$$
and which vanishes because you're in a static situation. To prove that this vanishes, consider the $k$th component of the integral of the current, exactly as in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/317957/how-can-one-prove-int-v-textdv-vec-a-0-given-that-vec-a-cdot-vec-tex), giving you
$$
\int j_k(\mathbf r)\mathrm d\mathbf r
=
\int \ue_k\cdot \mathbf j(\mathbf r)\mathrm d\mathbf r
=
\int \left[\nabla\cdot\left(x_k\mathbf j(\mathbf r)\right)-x_k\nabla\cdot\mathbf j(\mathbf r)\right]\mathrm d\mathbf r;
$$
here the second term vanishes because $\nabla\cdot\mathbf j(\mathbf r)=0$, and the first term goes over into the surface integral $\oint_\infty x_k\mathbf j(\mathbf r) \cdot\mathrm d\mathbf S$ at infinity, through the divergence theorem, and this surface integral vanishes since your current is spatially bounded.

---

The first nontrivial term is the dipole term, which comes from
$$
U_1 
= \int j_k(\mathbf r) x_l\frac{\partial A_k}{\partial x_l}(\z) \mathrm d \mathbf r
= \frac{\partial A_k}{\partial x_l}(\z) \int x_lj_k(\mathbf r) \mathrm d \mathbf r,
$$
and this already separates into a field times a moment of the current, but it's obviously not in the form we want it to be in; instead, we want it in the form $\mathbf B(\z)\cdot \mathbf m$, where $\mathbf B = \nabla\times\mathbf A$ and 
$$
\mathbf m = \frac12 \int \mathbf r\times\mathbf j(\mathbf r)\mathrm d\mathbf r.
$$
If you work out what we want to get, in all its glory, it's actually not that different, because it reads
\begin{align}
\mathbf B\cdot\mathbf m
& =
\varepsilon_{ikl}\frac{\partial A_l}{\partial x_k}(\z) \,\frac12 \int \varepsilon_{imn}x_mj_n(\mathbf r)\mathrm d\mathbf r
\\& =
\frac12(\delta_{km}\delta_{ln}-\delta_{kn}\delta_{lm})\frac{\partial A_l}{\partial x_k}(\z) \, \int x_mj_n(\mathbf r)\mathrm d\mathbf r
\\& =
\frac12\left[\frac{\partial A_l}{\partial x_k}(\z) \, \int x_kj_l(\mathbf r)\mathrm d\mathbf r 
-\frac{\partial A_l}{\partial x_k}(\z) \, \int x_lj_k(\mathbf r)\mathrm d\mathbf r\right],
\end{align}
and this is pretty close to what we have, except for that pesky term with the switched indices. To get a term of that form, you can use an integration-by-parts term as above, which looks as follows: we pull out of our hat the quantity $x_lx_k \,\mathbf j(\mathbf r)$ (much as above we used $x_k \,\mathbf j(\mathbf r)$) and we calculate the integral of its divergence, giving
\begin{align}
\int \nabla\cdot\left(x_lx_k \,\mathbf j(\mathbf r) \right)\mathrm d \mathbf r
& =
\int x_lj_k(\mathbf r) \mathrm d \mathbf r
+\int x_kj_l(\mathbf r) \mathrm d \mathbf r
+\int x_lx_k\,\nabla\cdot\mathbf j(\mathbf r) \mathrm d \mathbf r
.
\end{align}
Here the left-hand side vanishes, because we can pull it to a surface integral at the surface, away from the domain of the current, and the third term on the right also vanishes because the current is static and conserves charge; this means, then, that
$$
\int x_lj_k(\mathbf r) \mathrm d \mathbf r
+\int x_kj_l(\mathbf r) \mathrm d \mathbf r
=0,
$$
and we're essentially done - all that's left to do is to connect the dots.

---

And, as you can see, trying to do this one order above has nothing but a promise of pain in it, particularly because magnetic quadrupole fields and moments are used relatively rarely and that means that there aren't particularly solid conventions about how exactly one should define the moments, which then makes people a bit more reluctant to use the fields, and it all snowballs down.

To be frank, the magnetic-dipole calculation I've just done (and the electrostatic quadrupole you did in class) is really the highest order to which it makes sense to do the calculation explicitly; if you want to go higher, you really should be setting up a full calculation with arbitrary $l$, with consistent and clear definitions of both the current moments and the external fields at arbitrary multipolarities. Even there, though, it's remarkable that even Jackson forgoes going into those waters, which should tell you something about how worthwhile it is to go down that road.

Comment: You used Taylor expansion, yet obtained the zero'th and first order multipoles.  For some reason I was expecting the field needed to be expanded in vector spherical harmonics, as well as the current, and then due to their orthogonality the multipole terms just fall out into a sum.  I tried it but couldn't figure out how to massage the terms in the sum to look nice (like m.B).  I guess my question is what is the relationship between the taylor expansion and the spherical harmonic expansion?

Comment: @BuddyJohn The vector spherical harmonics expression is messier ;-). More fundamentally, the two series are very tightly related, because each vector spherical harmonics solution is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $l$, so it is in direct correspondence with that layer of the Taylor expansion. Of course, the two are not identical (hence the integration by parts), particularly since the VSHs are a strict subset of the homogeneous polynomials, but those extra polynomials are, at heart, gauge degrees of freedom that don't contribute.

Comment: Your answer is on the right track, but you get lost in keeping the $A_{lm}^u(r)$ unevaluated: commit to the Coulomb gauge, and keep only one family of harmonics, relating everything to the magnetic field at the origin and its derivatives. (Keep in mind that here $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ are solutions in vacuum - you are *not* solving for the self-energy of $\mathbf j$, you're solving for its interaction with an external field.) I can discuss further in chat if you're interested.

Comment: Yes, I would like to learn more.

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for, I'll try to derive the quadrupole term as an exercise. I know that only the electric quadrupole and magnetic dipole terms have non negligible magnitude, but I wanted to understand the general technique. Thank you