# Momentum conservation in classical electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, momentum, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, classical-field-theory, poynting-vector

The partial of tensor is equal

$$\partial_{\mu}T^{\mu j} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}T^{0j} + \nabla_{j} T^{ij} = -(\rho \vec{E} + \vec{j}\; \times \vec{B})^{j}$$

where does it come from?

In the equation above the term

$$T^{0j} = \vec{S} = \frac{1}{4 \pi}\vec{E} \; \times \vec{B}$$

I recognize as Poynting vector.

From momentum conservation

$$\frac{d\vec{P}^{j}}{dt}=0$$

follows equation

$$\frac{d\vec{P}^{j}}{dt}= - \int_{V} d^{3} x \rho E^{j} - \int_{V} d^{3} x (\vec{j} \; \times \vec{B})^{j} - \int_{V} d \sigma_{i} T^{ij}$$

where $$P = \int_{V} d^{3} x \vec{S}$$

I wanted to know what right hand side presents?

$$RHS = - \int_{V} d^{3} x \rho E^{j} - \int_{V} d^{3} x (\vec{j} \; \times \vec{B})^{j} - \int_{V} d \sigma_{i} T^{ij}$$

I've read that it is the Poynting vector evaluating in time, but I didn't see that.

Thank you for your explanation with mathematical description.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_stress_tensor

Comment: why did you edit an old question rather than create a new totally different one?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I couldn't create a new one.

Comment: Please do not edit a question to ask a completely different question. See e.g. [this meta answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9699/50583) for a list of reasons you might find yourself currently unable to post new questions. Trying to circumvent such system restrictions can result in longer suspensions, i.e. finding yourself completely unable to post on the site.

Comment: @ACuriousMind sorry I recognized this after posting and wasn’t sure what to do.

Comment: The calculation in my answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/83759/8563 might be of interest