# Quantum mechanics Clebsch–Gordan coefficients

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, quantum-states

For $j_{1} = 1 \; \text{and} \; j_{2}=1$ I know that $j = 2,1,0$ and $m = -2, -1, 0, 1, 2$.

All possible states in the grid are represented by dots:

[image]

Why for $m = 2 \; \text{and} \; j = 2$ there is a dot? Why not for $m = 2 \; \text{and} \; j = 1$?

How to calculate where dots should be placed?

Comment: Related : [Total spin of two spin- 1/2  particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/342123/total-spin-of-two-spin-1-2-particles/342156#342156).

Comment: This has nothing to do with Clebsch-Gordan coefficients and adding angular momenta. For *any* angular momentum, given a value for $j$, there are $2j+1$  possible values for $m$, running from $-j$ to $+j$ in steps of $1$. This follows from the commutation relations of $J_i$ and is derived in every QM textbook.

Comment: duplicate of v6 (now rolled back) of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/741720/36194) by a different OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tensor product (or the "spin sum") of two irreducible representations of spin $j_1$ and $j_2$ decomposes as the direct sum of irreps of spin $j=|j_1-j_2|$ to $j=j_1+j_2$. In other words, when you sum two spins $j_1$ and $j_2$, the total spin can take values $j=|j_1-j_2|, |j_1 - j_2| + 1, ..., j_1+j_2$. Each of these irreps of total spin $j$ host a multiplet with $J_3$ eigenvalues $m=-j, ...,j$. You can think of each of these $j$ as representing different orthogonal subspaces, in which we diagonalize $J_3$ with eigenvalues $m$ going from $-j$ to $j$

For example, here you want to take the tensor product  of two spin 1 irreps $j_1=1$ and $j_2 =1$, so $j=0,1,2$ runs from 1-1=0 to 1+1=2, and for each $j$, $m$ runs from $-j$ to $j$. This is depicted in your image. There are no dots placed on $m=2$ $j=1$ because $|m|\leq j$ in our construction

Let's take another example to confirm our understanding, with $j_1 = 2$, $j_2 = 1$, then $j=2-1,2,2+1$ which is to say $j=1,2,3$ and

For $j=1$, $m=-j,...,j$ which means $m=-1,0,1$

Similarily for $j=2$, $m=-2,-1,0,1,2$

For $j=3$, $m=-3,...,3$

Comment: I was calculating using formula $j = j_{1} + j_{2}, j_{1} + j_{2} - 1, ... , |j_{1} - j_{2}| $, $m = j, j - 1, ... , -j$ If I understand correctly, with $j_{1} = 2$, $j_{2} = 1$ for $j = 2$ it will be three dots, because m = -2, 1, 2. Am I correct?

Comment: @PawełChmolewski No, that’s not correct. See my comment on your question.